# An exception of type System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was thrown. Additional exception information: The data is invalid

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration-wizard, standalone

I have an issue while running the SharePoint 2010 configuration Wizard.

I'm getting an error while running this wizard.

"Failed to create the configuration database."

"An exception of type System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was thrown. Additional exception information: The data is invalid."

Im trying to install a Standalone SharePoint 2010 Server on Windows 7 64 bit OS.
Before starting the SharePoint installation I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2010.

Troubleshooting steps already performed:

I have already tried performing troubleshooting steps mentioned in the below blog.

_http://sp-scripting.blogspot.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2010-exception-of-type.html.

performing these steps didn't resolve my issue but there was a change in the error.

**OLD Error:**

"Failed to create the configuration database."

"An exception of type System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was thrown. Additional exception information: Keyset does not exist."

**NEW Error:**
"Failed to create the configuration database."

"An exception of type System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was thrown. Additional exception information: The data is invalid."

Let me know if you need more information.

**FULL ERROR MSG:**

ERR                                              Failed to create the configuration database.
An exception of type System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Keyset does not exist

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Keyset does not exist

at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandle._FreeCSP(IntPtr pProvCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandle.ReleaseHandle()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalDispose()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPCertificateAuthority.Provision()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Create(SqlConnectionStringBuilder configurationDatabase, SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase, IdentityType identityType, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword, SecureString masterPassphrase)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.Create(SqlConnectionStringBuilder configurationDatabase, SqlConnectionStringBuilder administrationContentDatabase, String farmUser, SecureString farmPassword, SecureString masterPassphrase)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.CreateOrConnectConfigDb()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ConfigurationDatabaseTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Thanks

Comment: once you removed the FarmAdmin registry key, you have to reboot the server and then run the config wizard agian.

Comment: I again deleted the FarmAdmin Reg key and this time rebooted the system.
Now its giving me below error.

"Failed to create the configuration database."

"An exception of type System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException was thrown. Additional exception information: Keyset does not exist."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved after formatting my machine.
I guess, it was some Active Directory connectivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

For keySet Data does not exist means that protected services is not started.

To resolve the issue please start the **[Start the Protected Storage service](http://computerstepbystep.com/protected_storage_service.html)** and run the config wizard.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2781614

Becuase you tried many times what i would suggest.

- Clear the Regirtry entry
- Set the Permission
- Reboot
- make sure Proctect storage Service is running
- Now run the Config wizard.

Comment: Yes, when I checked, my Protect Storage service was stopped.
I followed the steps you suggested to me, but still im getting the same error.

First config wizard run after the restart of my system throws, 'Keyset does not exist' error.

immediate second config wizard run throws, 'the data is invalid' error.

any other suggestions?